# Spark: Check whether a value exists in a nested array without exploding

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataset like below:

```
val df = Seq(("beatles", Seq(Seq("help", "hey jude"))), 
            ("romeo", Seq(Seq("help2", "hey judge"),Seq("help3", "they judge")))).toDF("col1", "col2")

root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I want to add a column to the dataframe, `hasHitSong`, which will iterate the sequence of hitsongs under col2, check if a hit song exist, for eg. "Hey Jude" and mark it as 1, else 0.

```
| col1    | col2                                            | hasHitSongs |
|---------|-------------------------------------------------|-------------|
| beatles | ["help", "hey jude"]                            | 1           |
| romeo   | [["help2", "hey judge"],["help3", "hey judge"]] | 0           |
```

Is there a way to do this without exploding the column col2 and just iterating the nested arrays under col2?

Comment: you can use [array_contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#array_contains) and [flatten](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#flatten) i.e array_contains(flatten(col2), "Hey Jude")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using spark version 2.4 or higher version:

> Using built-in function

```
df.withColumn("hasHitSongs", array_contains(flatten(col("col2")), "hey jude"))
```

> Using higher order function

```
df.withColumn("hasHitSongs, expr("exists(col2, a -> exists(a, b -> b = 'hey jude'))"))
```